# Persistent basic access Authentication

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, http-authentication

I know one can easily create a "Remember me" option for cookie based authentication login systems. Is such a thing also possible for basic access HTTP authentication?

Usually, the credentials the browser caches are flushed once the browser is closed. Can they be preserved somehow?

Comment: HTTP authentication or normal authentication, doesn't matter, if cookie already there then bypass authentication

Comment: Let's say we are in a situation that disallows the usage of cookies.

Comment: That's the browser business to manage when it should send and store credentials. There is no way to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way is to let the user use the automatic remembering of credentials provided by the browser.